# Javascript: is there a data structure, "matrix", thing[x][y]?

Tags: javascript

I don't know the terminology but I want to get it simpler:

```
var thingTopic1 =['hello','hallo', ..., 'hej'];
var thingTopic2 =['a','b',...,'c'];
...
var thingTopic999 =['x,'y',...,'?'];
```

so I want to access the data like `thing[para1][para2]`, is there some ready data structure for it or do I need to create messy function with the things? Please, note that sizes of things differ.

Comment: so.. what would `thing[5][10]` bring back ? which item from which array?

Comment: Gaby: 1st par = topic, 2nd par = unit number.  So 10th item from thingTopic5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no data structure for that, but you can easily accomplish it by combining arrays.

You can create an array that contains arrays, which is called a jagged array:

```
var thing = [
  ['hello','hallo','goddag','guten tag','nuqneH','hej'],
  ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'],
  ['x,'y','z']
];
```

Notice how the inner arrays can have different length, which is where the term "jagged" comes from.

Answer (score 2):

You can have arrays of arrays, and the size of each row can be different.

```
 var matrix = [
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [7, 8, 9],
   [0]
 ];
```

The variable "matrix" will refer to an array with length 4. The syntax you use to refer to (say) the "5" in the second row is exactly what you suggested:

```
 var theFive = matrix[1][1];
```

You can "build" a matrix like that incrementally of course.

```
 var matrix = [];
 for (var i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
   var row = ~~((i - 1) / 3);
   if (!matrix[row]) matrix[row] = [];
   matrix[row][(i - 1) % 3] = i;
 }
 matrix.push([0]);
```

When you set an integer-indexed "property" of an Array instance, Javascript makes sure that the "length" property of the array is updated. It does *not* allocate space for "holes" in the array, so if you set element number 200 first, there's still just one thing in the array, even though "length" would be 201.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantages from OOP of ES6 :

```
class Matrix extends Array {

   constructor(...rows) {
      if(rows.some( r => !Array.isArray(r)))
       throw new TypeError('Constructor accepts  only rows as array')

      super(...rows)
   }

   push(...rows) {
     if(rows.some( r => !Array.isArray(r)))
       throw new TypeError('Push method accepts array(s)')

     super.push(...rows)

   }

}
```

## Use case 1:

[image]

## Use case 2 :

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to object-oriented programming of Ecmascript 6? Do you need to source some lib and why not ES7?

Comment: ES7 not supported by all browsers .